# How to avoid type checking

Tags: java, oop, generics, design-patterns

I am working on a project which has some GameObject. It can be anything a ball, a coin, a plant.  And I have to pass the list of GameObject to some other class which renders the objects on-screen.

The GameObjects can be moveable and non-moveable. Some GameObjects can allow passing objects through them(Pervious) and some not. Some GameObjetcs have thrones (which might explode the ball) and some not. Some GameObjects are coins which are collected when the ball hits them.

So I did this -

```
Class GameObject{

// All things common to both entities. 
// Feilds - hasThrones, canPassthrough, isCoin
...
...
}

Class MovingGameObject extends GameObject implements Moveable{
    moveable logic;
...
...
}

Class FlyingGameObject extends GameObject implements Flyable{
    Flyable logic;
...
...
}
```

And I now have a  List < GameObjects >.

**Problem** 
When I am making the moveable objects move, I am doing something like:

```
if gameobject is an instance of MovingGameObject{
        // do something
}

if gameobject is an instance of FlyingGameObject{
        // do something
}
```

I know this is bad code. How do I refactor it to not use type checking?

One way I can think of is using lists. But That's not really a way as now what if I want a swimming object now? Then I do have to store in a new list for swimming objects.

Thanks

Comment: Use [Polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html). You shouldn't have to care about the type of the object.

Comment: Please include valid code snippets with correct spelling, capitalization, etc. If you want others to put effort into helping you, demonstrating you put effort into the question will help.

Comment: Also, what is "do something"? Is it something all `GameObject`s can do? Or something only (for instance) a `MovingGameObject` can do?

Comment: if you are using an interface and call  `#move`, why you have to check for implementation? For example abstract method in game object class, that you call without checking the implementation, and you pass in your subclasses the implementation. In top level you just call move method whatever if it flies or walk.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Only a MovingGameObject can do.

Comment: Rather you should check if instances of the interfaces if you only need to call the interface methods (but you'll still need the cast)

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes! I want to avoid casting and type checking all togther.

Comment: I guess this isn't a very good example, because flying is a type of movement, so `Flying` is a subtype of `Moving`. Other than that, [object capability pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/the-capability-pattern-future-) seems to be a good trick. It won't relieve you of casting completely, but it will condence class checking and casting down to a specific place in your code, so it's at least manageable.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use GameObject as an abstract class and define a common behavior

```
abstract class GameObject{
    // fields etc. ..
    // maybe some implementation

    // the "do something method"
    public abstract void doSomething();
}
```

When you extend it, you can pass your implementation in doSomethingMethod

```
class MovingGameObjectOne extends GameObject implements Moveable {
    moveable logic;
    @Override
    moveableMethod1() { }
    @Override
    moveableMethod2() { }
    @Override
    moveableMethod3() { }
    @Override
    doSomething() { 
        moveableMethod1();
        moveableMethod2();
        moveableMethod3();
        // you don't have to check for instance as it is implementation
    }
}
```

Same for other special flying and moveable objects

Then in your process, implementation is hidden

```
GameObject instance1 = new MoveableObjectOne();
GameObject instance2 = new FlyingObjectTwo();
instance1.doSomething(); // <- the block of your if is in implementation
instance2.doSomething(); // <- the block of your if is in implementation
anotherMethodForExample(instance1);
anotherMethodForExample(instance2);

private void anotherMethodForExample(GameObject parameterIsAnInterface) {
    parameterIsAnInterface.doSomething(); // <- the block of your if is in implementation
}
```

It's called strategy pattern. Hope this is what you are looking for, objects have actions, and they are called, whatever they do when they act.

Comment: ... and the GameObjects which are not moving the `dosomething` method is empty?

Comment: Some GameObjects cannot move?

Comment: Not all the objects move. Thts why I extended the normal GameObject class to MovingGameObject and added a Moveable for strategy.

Comment: Yes other objects do other stuff, but only the moving or flying implementation are called for moving objects. If you think about other non-moving objects the method will be called but they will do something different.

Comment: Last thing, is adding an empty method considered bad practice? Also, How about empty interface just to provide some type?

Comment: I don't understand something : if your non-moving objects are in the block of code, where you were checking for type, they do also something different, not moving but something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200017/discussion-between-lynxx-and-paul).